# How to android app from scratch from an existing android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

I have already published a Android App on Google Playstore. Now I want to revamped my existing app. I am developing my app using Android Studio.

I want to know what things should I kept same from previous one so that when I will publish revamped App on playstore it goes as a update to users? Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Package Name of the updated APK needs to be the same as the current version
2. The Version Code needs to be greater than that current version
3. The updated APK needs to be signed with the same signature as the current version.

Source :
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to keep following things same as in your previous version of the already published app.
1.Package name of updated app should be same as previous one

2.same signed signature as per previous version of the app

Also make sure that version code of new app should be greater than the current version

once you upload your updated version of the app it'll be in update pending status once your update is accepted by google playstore your app user will be notified that update is available for your app.

you can get full detailed answer from 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en